# How to prove $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb {N}} [n, \infty) = [1, \infty)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction

> What is $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb {N}} [n, \infty)$?

---

I know that $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb {N}} [n, \infty) = [1, \infty)$, but I'm not sure how to prove it with mathematical induction.

Comment: You don't need induction. What you need is the **definition** of the interval $[n,\infty)$.

Comment: How could you use induction here? To use induction, you need some property $P(n)$ which depends on $n$ and from which you can deduce $P(n+1)$. What do you think $P(n)$ is?

Comment: @User8128 $P(1) = [1, \infty), P(n) = [n, \infty)$ and $P(n+1) = [n+1, \infty)$.

Comment: In induction, $P(n)$ is a mathematical sentence which can be true or false. But $[n,\infty)$ is an interval, not a mathematical sentence that can be true or false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check both inclusions.

First, $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}[n,\infty) \subseteq [1,\infty)$. *Proof.* Let $x \in \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}[n,\infty)$. Then for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $x \in [n, \infty)$. But for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $[n, \infty) \subseteq [1, \infty)$. So, $x \in [1, \infty)$, and the proof of the first inclusion is complete.

Second, $[1,\infty) \subseteq \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}[n,\infty)$. *Proof.* This is obvious by considering $n=1$ on the right-hand side of the inclusion to be proved.

Hence, $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}[n,\infty) =[1,\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

$\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}[n,\infty)=[1,\infty)$ since for all $m>n$, $[m,\infty)\subset[n,\infty)$.

Comment: Could you please be more specific with the proof? I think you can't just automatically assume that if $m>n$, then $[m,\infty)\subset[n,\infty)$. Mathematical induction is required.

Comment: If $x\in [m,\infty)$, then this means that $m\leq x<\infty$. Hence, $n<m\leq x<\infty$ so that $n<x<\infty$. In particular, $n\leq x<\infty$ so that $x\in[n,\infty)$. No induction required.